# How can I use pagination on two div elements where only one is visible at a time

Tags: html, coldfusion, pagination, coldfusion-9

I just graduated so I don't have much experience on programming. 
I am using a jQuery function `slideToggle()` to switch between displaying one of two div elements. Both div's display rows of data and I am trying to use pagination since there are over 50 records on each div. 
Everything seems fine so far. Refresh the page and first div is visible, pagination is working just as it should.

The problem starts when I click on the button that runs a jQuery function to switch to the other div. The second div is displayed (first one disappeared, which is fine). When I click on a page number the browser redirects me to the first div and starts showing the results from first div. 
I think this is normal because on page refreshing the browser runs the default values but I do not know how to solve this situation. I would appreciate any help. Forgot to mention this is ColdFusion.

What I done so far is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="logic.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#E8ECED">

    <div id="header">
      <h1>BHA Toyota</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <cfset pageSize=15/>
      <cfset recordCount=100/>
      <cfset intStart=1/>
      <div style="min-height:40px">
        <div id="title">Top 30 Live Outbound Calls</div>
        <div id="switchDealershipsButton">
          <span id="switchDealers" role="button" tabindex="0">Switch to Showcase Honda</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="texasHonda" class="row">
        <cfparam name="url.pageNumber" type="string" default=""/>
        <cfset pageNumber=#url.pageNumber#/>
        <cfquery name="texasHondaLiveOutbandCalls" datasource="callmeasurement">
          SELECT refname, callid, cf_frn_dnisid, tz_datetime
          FROM [dbo].[lskin] AS ls
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[dnis] as dn
          ON ls.lskinid=dn.add_lskinid
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[xcall_long] AS xl
          ON dn.dnisdbid=xl.cf_frn_dnisid
          WHERE isoutbound=1 AND frn_xcall_dispositionid=1 AND refname='BHA - Texas Toyota'
          ORDER BY tz_datetime DESC
          OFFSET #pageSize# *(#pageNumber#-1) ROWS
          FETCH NEXT #pageSize# ROWS only;
        </cfquery>

        <cftable query="texasHondaLiveOutbandCalls" htmlTable="true" colHeaders="true">
          <cfcol width="30" header="Account Name" text="<em>#texasHondaLiveOutbandCalls.refname#</em>">
          <cfcol width="23" header="Call ID" text="<em>#texasHondaLiveOutbandCalls.callid#</em>">
          <cfcol width="20" header="Line ID" text="<em>#texasHondaLiveOutbandCalls.cf_frn_dnisid#</em>">
          <cfcol width="30" header="Date/Time of Call" text="<em>#texasHondaLiveOutbandCalls.tz_datetime#</em>">
        </cftable>
        <cfoutput>
          <cfloop index="intPage" from="1" to="#Ceiling(recordCount / 10 )#">
            <!---
            Calculate the start value based on the
            current page.
        --->
            <cfset intStart=(1 + ((intPage - 1) * 10))/>
            <!--- Output paginating link. --->
            <a href="#CGI.script_name#?pageNumber=#intPage#">
              #intPage#</a>
          </cfloop>
        </cfoutput>
      </div>
      <div id="showcaseHonda" class="row" style="display:none">
        <cfparam name="url.pageNumber" type="string" default=""/>
        <cfset pageNumber=#url.pageNumber#/>
        <cfquery name="showcaseHondaLiveOutbandCalls" datasource="callmeasurement">
          SELECT refname, callid, cf_frn_dnisid, tz_datetime
          FROM [dbo].[lskin] AS ls
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[dnis] as dn
          ON ls.lskinid=dn.add_lskinid
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[xcall_long] AS xl
          ON dn.dnisdbid=xl.cf_frn_dnisid
          WHERE isoutbound=1 AND frn_xcall_dispositionid=1 AND refname='BHA - Showcase Honda'
          ORDER BY tz_datetime DESC
          OFFSET #pageSize# *(#pageNumber#-1) ROWS
          FETCH NEXT #pageSize# ROWS only;
        </cfquery>
        <div class="table">
          <cfoutput query="showcaseHondaLiveOutbandCalls">
            <div class="tableRow">
              <div class="tableCell">
                #showcaseHondaLiveOutbandCalls.refname#</div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                #showcaseHondaLiveOutbandCalls.callid#</div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                #showcaseHondaLiveOutbandCalls.cf_frn_dnisid#</div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                #showcaseHondaLiveOutbandCalls.tz_datetime#</div>
            </div>
          </cfoutput>

          <cfoutput>
            <cfloop index="intPage" from="1" to="#Ceiling(recordCount / 10 )#">
              <!---
            Calculate the start value based on the
            current page.
        --->
              <cfset intStart=(1 + ((intPage - 1) * 10))/>
              <!--- Output paginating link. --->
              <a href="#CGI.script_name#?pageNumber=#intPage#">
                #intPage#</a>
            </cfloop>
          </cfoutput>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#switchDealers').click(function() 
  {
    var dealerOnScreen = $('#switchDealers').text();
    
    if(dealerOnScreen === "Switch to Showcase Honda")
    
    $('#texasHonda').slideToggle("slow", texasToyota);
    else 
    
     $('#showcaseHonda').slideToggle("slow", showcaseHonda);
    
   });
   
  function texasToyota() {
     $('#showcaseHonda').slideToggle("slow");
      $('#switchDealers').text("Switch to Texas Toyota");
    }
    
    
   function showcaseHonda() {
      $('#texasHonda').slideToggle("slow");
       $('#switchDealers').text("Switch to Showcase Honda"); 
     }
  
  });
```

Comment: Can you post the JS code shows how you are using `slideToggle()`?

Comment: I took a quick glimpse of the visible code.  Why would your default page number be an empty string instead of 1?

Comment: No good reason for that, just luck of experience lol. It was failing when page was loading for the first time because was undifined so I added an empty string but it makes more sense to be 1 and not "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys, I was able to solve the problem. I am posting the answer in here if someone comes across this question later on.

I added another variable called "section" where I create the pagination link for the second div(the one that was having the problem. The I check if the variable section is defined (which means the pagination link for the second div is clicked). If it is defined browser get refresh but I hide the first div and show the second div.

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop index="intPage" from="1" to="#Ceiling(recordCount / 10)#">

        <cfset intStart = (1 + ((intPage - 1) * 10))/>

<!--- Output paginating link. --->
            <a href="#CGI.script_name#?pageNumber=#intPage#&section=2">#intPage#</a>

    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>



<cfif isDefined("section") and section EQ 2>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#showcaseHonda').show();
                texasToyotaHide();
            });
        </script>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Nice job. Might also consider giving the div's sequential id's, ie "dealership1" and "dealership2". Then you could do something a little more dynamic like this:  https://jsfiddle.net/8tegj7da/8/

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for comments ...)

As an aside, since you mentioned being new to CF, a few suggestions and tips about the code

1. **Never** use raw client variables in sql, because it exposes the database to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead use [cfqueryparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html), which among other benefits, prevents raw parameters from being executed as sql commands. So it can be used anywhere a literal is expected. (It cannot be used with object names). Since [OFFSET / FETCH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=sql.110).aspx) expects a simple number, it *should* work here. If not, you will have to scrub the url parameters first, such as using [val()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/val.html) to ensure a numeric value.
2. Try and avoid using the CF UI tags (cftable, cfcol, cfform, etcetera). Most are outdated and buggy. Not to mention difficult customize. I had to look up `cftable` in the documentation to find out what it does, but looks like you could replace it with a plain html `<table>` and a query loop.
3. Though it will work either way, separating database and HTML makes for cleaner, more readable code. The usual convention is to place queries and parameter declarations first, then any display code. (You could also move the database logic into a [cfcomponent](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcomponent.html).)

   ```
    <!--- initialize variables --->
    <cfparam name="url.pageNumber" default=""/>

    <!--- retrieve data --->
    <cfquery ...>.. sql statement here</cfquery>
    <cfquery ...>.. sql statement here</cfquery>

    <!--- presentation code --->
    <html>
    <head>
    ... rest of display code ...
    </body>
    </html>
   ```
4. `CFParam` creates a variable if it does not already exist. So no need for multiple `cfparam` declarations for the same variable. The first one will get the job done, and the others will end up being ignored.
5. Pound signs are not needed nearly as frequently as you might think. *Usually* they are only necessary when using a variable inside `<cfoutput>` or when a variable is placed inside quotes. So use:

   ```
    <cfset pageNumber= url.pageNumber/>
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
    <cfset pageNumber= #url.pageNumber#/>
   ```

   Though in this specific case there is no need to copy `url.pageNumber` into another variable. Just use `url.pageNumber` directly in your code.